# jquery plugin function throws undefined function error

Tags: jquery

Trying to use a tag plugin https://timseverien.com/projects/taggd/, got the basic part ok. When I try to call a function, it says function not defined.

```
taggd.show()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aW8ZY/40/

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: taggd is a function and has no property "show" - what are you triying to do with `taggd.show()` - @RoryMcCrossan jsfiddle works for me

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you look in the author page, it says tagged.show() can be used. fiddle works, but the .show() ( and there are update functions I wish to use) are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`taggd` var is undefined... either chain the `.show()` or assign a `var`.

**Chain:**

```
$('.item').taggd( options, data ).hide().show(1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pensfqw/

**Assign a var:** (as your original code, just assigned a var `taggd`)

```
var taggd = $('.item').taggd( options, data );
taggd.hide();
taggd.show(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

taggd is a jQuery plugin, so it needs to be used with a jQuery selector, like this:

```
$('.taggd').taggd( options, data );
```

The examples given by the plugin website require that the variable `taggd` has already been assigned and can therefore be used like this:

```
var taggd = $('.taggd').taggd( options, data );
taggd.hide();
taggd.show();
```

(Admittedly, this is not particularly clear in their examples.)

Alternatively, you can simple chain commands like this:

```
$('.taggd').taggd( options, data ).hide().show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aW8ZY/44/

Comment: @CaseyRule OMG, did you write all that choral music on your page? I am a big fan!

Comment: Haha yes I did!  I never imagined anyone would actually find my music from StackOverflow

Comment: @CaseyRule I was thinking the same thing. I was like, what a place to find some awesome music. :) I hope you keep writing. I am a big fan of choral music. Thomas tallis being a name I remember to follow :)